# Finding maximum value across multiple columns (pmax gives NAs)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using `reshape` function, I have data that looks something like this:

```
df1

ID Score1  Score2  Score3
1  2       3       1
2  3       2       1
3  2       1       NA 
4  1       NA      NA
```

As you can see, some of my score variables have missing values.

I'm interested in finding the maximum score variable for all ID values. When I tried using `pmax(df1$Score1,df1$Score2,df1$Score3)`, my resulting vector contains NAs. I'm not sure why this is, as I know that my Score1 variable doesn't contain any NAs.

This is what I'd like my output to accomplish:

```
ID MaxScore
1  3
2  3
3  2
4  1
```

Thanks

Comment: Or in the style that you started `pmax(df1$Score1,df1$Score2,df1$Score3, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: the na.rm=T did the trick @G5W. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `apply` on each row (`MARGIN = 1`)

```
apply(X = df1[,-1], MARGIN = 1, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3 3 2 1
```

Comment: I like the explicit mention of the arguments.  Good exposition.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the vectorized `pmax` to get this done

```
cbind(df1['ID'], MaxScore = do.call(pmax, c(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE)))
#   ID MaxScore
#1  1        3
#2  2        3
#3  3        2
#4  4        1
```